# What template engine should I use in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, templates, template-engine

I'm learning Spring MVC and want to create a site. The main problem is a *template system*. Should I use JSP / JSF / Apache FreeMarker / Thymeleaf or something else?

I saw a lot of discussion on this subject, but they are all outdated. So, I'm curious, what is fine now?

Comment: Two answers, the two suggest *thymeleaf*. I'll go for it. I made a small project some months ago using Spring MVC+Thymeleaf and I'm really pleased.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The best practices for server-side rendering have shifted towards using a *template engine*. These get the responsibility to merge the data with the template into the actual output.

Current preferences appear to be:

- [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/)
- [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/)

JSP's and JSF are entirely different things and have become out of fashion.

The big plus for using an actual template engine is that you are forced to separate the concerns of gathering the data to present and rendering it; this separation allows you to (unit) test the templates.

Note, however, that the industry is shifting once more towards *client-side rendering*, where the server just returns the data as JSON-objects and the web application uses some framework like Angular, React, jQuery or Ember to build the pages.

*Note on the edit: Originally the list included Velocity, but that is no longer supported by Spring.*

Comment: Note, that Velocity support is removed from Spring since 5.0.1 : https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13795

Answer (score 15):

You can use any of them as they are supported. JSP, FreeMaker and Thymeleaf are similar by idea: you create a *template* to be rendered. JSP and FreeMaker lacks some features that are available in Thymeleaf.

I like Thymeleaf's idea where you can load your template to the browser and see how the page is going to be rendered (real). **Thymeleaf template is fully featured HTML page.** That's not possible in JSP where you have JSP tags and FreeMaker where you have *placeholders*.

JSF is *component* based so that's a different approach.

If I have to choose I would use Thymeleaf.

Comment: the statement about thymeleaf being a fully rendered page is not exactly true as you can still use fragments to compose a complete page from small chunks. But you are right in the sense, the `th:XXX` fields doesn't show up int he final render and you can have place holders to make the rendering look better.

Answer (score 4):

There are many template engines available out there. But Spring Boot officially supports Thymeleaf, FreeMarker, Mustache and Groovy Templates. My preference is `Thymeleaf` because of its extendability.

There is a detailed comparison on various aspects of template engines explained in my post:
https://springhow.com/spring-boot-template-engines-comparison/

Comment: here is performance comparison https://ozkanpakdil.github.io/spring-comparing-template-engines/